# Calibrate fisheye image lens

Tags: python, opencv

I am using a fisheye camera and I would like to calibrate it and correct its barrel distortion using OpenCV. But I 've been following ths approach but it raises an error.

```
CHECKERBOARD = (6,9)
subpix_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1)
calibration_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW
objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)

objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

### read images and for each image:
img = cv2.imread(fname)
print(fname)
img_shape = img.shape[:2]

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2_imshow(gray)
# Find the chess board corners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
print(ret,corners)
# If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)
    cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(3,3),(-1,-1),subpix_criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners)
###
print(objpoints,imgpoints)
# calculate K & D
N_imm = len(objpoints)
print(N_imm) # number of calibration images
K = np.zeros((3, 3))
D = np.zeros((4, 1))
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_imm)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_imm)]
retval, K, D, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(
    objpoints,
    imgpoints,
    gray.shape[::-1],
    K,
    D,
    rvecs,
    tvecs,
    calibration_flags,
    (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 1e-6))
```

## Error

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     41     tvecs,
     42     calibration_flags,
---> 43     (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 1e-6))

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp:713: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !objectPoints.empty() && !imagePoints.empty() && objectPoints.total() == imagePoints.total() in function 'calibrate'
```

Do anyone have an answer please ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Med! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You should add assertion to the code after reading image (`assert img is not None`), and after the result of findChessboardCorners (`assert ret is True`). In other words, make sure that the image is read and chessboard is found.

Comment: You are right, I've found that ret and corners were empty what does it mean ? how can I fix it ? thank you.

Comment: It means that the function could not find chessboard in the image. Try giving a sample image that contains chessboard and have a visual feedback with [drawChessboardCorners](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#drawchessboardcorners) when ret becomes true, like in [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html).